# Using variabled when assigning ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having troubles using variables to assign my `ng-model` values, despite doing what I've seen done on a few examples on the net. Here's my short snippet:

```
<div ng-repeat='arg in module.args'>
    <fieldset ng-if='arg.type=="int"' class="form-group">
        <input ng-model='models[arg.name]' type="text" id="{{ arg.name }}">
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

When I look at the `<input>` in the browser with dev tools, it shows this:

```
<input class="ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="models[arg.name]" id="another_int" type="text">
```

As you can see the `models[arg.name]` is used as-is. Where I would expect the `arg.name` to be the same as the `id`, that is, I want angular to use the object's name.

I also tried:

```
<input ng-model='models[$index]' type="text" id="{{ arg.name }}">
```

But again, the variable is not interpreted, it's sent as is.

I also tried:

```
<input ng-model='{{ models[$index] }}' type="text" id="{{ arg.name }}">
```

but that just throws an error.

**How can I use variables in my `ng-model` attributes?**

Comment: It should work as you tried, even if the dev tools don't replace the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar example that works. Note that the dev tools don't replace the variable name.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in configuration.metaData">

<label>{{key}}</label>

<input data-ng-model="configuration[key]" name="{{key}}" placeholder="{{key}}">
```

Comment: You are right, I was expecting the name to be inserted. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I was having the same issue and trying to verify with dev tools which didn't work.